# PyCharm spell-checking: how to remove a word (mistakenly) added to the dictionary?

Tags: pycharm, spell-checking

In which dictionary exactly do words added with Right mouse click -> Spelling -> 'Typo: Save 'foo' to dictionary' go? How to remove them from there?

Comment: Yes, that solves it. Do you have any idea where this word list is saved (to be able to backup and / or export it?) It's cumbersome to type or individually accept all these across projects...

Comment: I don't know if it is possible export the whole dictionary. maybe you can import a custom one

Comment: Yes > custom dictionary.
In Linux, place your own dictionary under `~/.config/spell-checking/` and call it, e.g. `my-technical.dic`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want remove a word from the dictionary you can go to:

```
Settings->Editor->Spelling
```

Now you should see a window with two tabs, **Accepted Words** and **Dictionaries**.

Click on the first one (**Accepted Words**) and click on the word that you want remove.

After this press on **minus icon** on the right of the page to remove the word.